# What's the meaning of "Make a play for it"?

Tags: meaning

I checked the phrase in Cambridge Dictionary and it means

> "to try to get something, or start a relationship with someone, sometimes by using a plan"  but I don't now what the meaning is in this case.So,

Could you please explain what the meaning of "Make a play for it" is in this text?

The full text is:

> That evening, Shawn saddled a new horse, a copper-coated mare, for the
>   first time. She was ready for a short ride, Shawn said, so we mounted, him
>   on the mare, me on Bud. We made it about half a mile up the mountain,
>   moving deliberately so as not to frighten the horses, winding our way
>   through the wheat fields. Then I did something foolish. I got too close to
>   the mare. She didn’t like having the gelding behind her, and with no
>   warning she leapt forward, thrusting her weight onto her front legs, and
>   with her hind legs kicked Bud full in the chest.
>   Bud went berserk.
>   I’d been tying a knot in my reins to make them more secure and didn’t
>   have a firm hold. Bud gave a tremendous jolt, then began to buck, throwing
>   his body in tight circles. The reins flew over his head. I gripped the saddle
>   horn and squeezed my thighs together, curving my legs around his bulging
>   belly. Before I could get my bearings, Bud took off at a dead run straight up
>   a ravine, bucking now and then but running, always running. My foot
>   slipped through a stirrup up to my calf...**My instincts told me to let go of the saddle horn**—the only thing keeping
>   me on the horse. If I let go I’d fall, but I’d have a precious moment to reach
>   for the flapping reins or try to yank my calf from the stirrup. **Make a play
>   for it, my instincts screamed.**
>   Those instincts were my guardians. They had saved me before, guiding
>   my movements on a dozen bucking horses, telling me when to cling to the
>   saddle and when to pitch myself clear of pounding hooves. They were the
>   same instincts that, years before, had prompted me to hoist myself from
>   the scrap bin when Dad was dumping it, because they had understood, even
>   if I had not, that it was better to fall from that great height rather than hope
>   Dad would intervene. All my life those instincts had been instructing me in
>   this single doctrine—that the odds are better if you rely only on yourself.
>   Bud reared, thrusting his head so high I thought he might tumble
>   backward. He landed hard and bucked. **I tightened my grip on the horn,
>   making a decision, based on another kind of instinct, not to surrender my
>   hold.**
>   *Educated* by Tara Westover

Comment: It refers exactly to one of her two choices to get out of the dangerous situation after she lets go of the saddle horn: reach for the flapping reins **or** try to yank my foot from the stirrup. One of those two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To make a play (for something)* is an idiomatic expression that means to try and achieve some difficult objective. Example:

> The batter swings! It's a looping grounder to far right field!  He's rounded first and is **making a play** for second ... Safe!

In your example the narrator must first let go of the saddle horn and risk falling from the horse, in order *try to reach* the reins and retake control.

Answer (score 3):

"to try to get something" - to attain a goal (of reaching the reins or freeing her boot from the stirrup, and thus remaining on the horse, despite its bucking).

Comment: But she says "My instincts told me to let go of the saddle horn"

Comment: Her instincts told her to let go of the saddle horn (which felt safe) and instead reach for the flapping reins or try to yank her calf from the stirrup.